# JQUERY: Possible to combine drag and drop with jcarousel?

Tags: jquery-ui

Just a general question. Does anyone know if it's possible to combine jquery drag/drop with jcarousel? I want to be able to drop images INTO a carousel. If it's possible, could someone point me in the right direction for finding a tutorial or some sort of guidance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I figured this out myself. Here's a rough idea of what I did in case it helps anyone else. There is a list of available products and a carousel. Before dragging any products into it, a "DRAG ITEMS HERE" message is centered across the carousel, which is achieved via css layering. The droppable area includes both that message and the carousel, which is underneath the message. Once an item is moved into the drop area, the overlying message is removed and the size of the carousel is incremented. You have to start at zero because jcarousel will auto fill with the first item. Starting at zero over-writes that auto-created item. I also had to add a floated delete button over the top of the item in the carousel which is the "<div class=\"RemoveItem\"></div>". Because there is a floated add button over the available product, I had to add a class ("ImagePosition") to give the product itself relative positioning, which is removed on the drag so it will leave the available products container. Lots going on. At any rate, it's not perfect, but it works. I'm way interested in hearing refinements.

```
<div class="ProductBundlerOverlay" id="dialogProductBundler" style="display: none;">
    <div class="Inner">
        <div class="BundlerTop">
            <div class="CloseWindow" onclick="$('#dialogProductBundler').dialog('close');">
                <div class="Text">Close</div>
                <div class="Button"><img src="bundler/CloseBtn.png" alt="Close" border="0" /></div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="BundlerTitle" class="BundlerTitle"></div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="BundlerDesc" class="BundlerDesc"></div>
        <div id="Bundler" class="Bundler ui-widget-content">
            <div class="PlaceHolder">DRAG ITEMS HERE</div>
            <ul id="bundlerCarousel" class="DropArea jcarousel-skin-tango">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="BundlerTotal" class="BundlerTotal"></div>
        <div id="AvailableProducts" class="AvailableProducts">
            <ul>
                [this content dynamically created using jquery]
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#bundlerCarousel').jcarousel({
            visible: 5,
            itemLoadCallback: itemLoadCallbackFunction
        });
    })
</script>
```

IN A SCRIPT FILE OR IN SCRIPT TAGS:

```
var varCarouselSize = 0;
$(".Image").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find("div").remove()
        $(this).removeClass("ImagePosition")
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("ImagePosition").append("<div class=\"AddItem\"></div>").click(function() {
        })
    }
});


$("#Bundler").droppable({
    accept: ".Image",
    //activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    //hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        //alert("size " + varCarouselSize);
        if (varCarouselSize == 0)
        {
            $(".PlaceHolder").remove();
            varCarouselSize = 1;
        }
        var el=$("<li class=\"ItemContainer\"><div class=\"RemoveItem\"></div>" + ui.draggable.clone().html() + "</li>").filter('li').find('div.RemoveItem').click(function(){el.remove()}).end();
        $("#bundlerCarousel").jcarousel('size',varCarouselSize);
        $("#bundlerCarousel").jcarousel('add', varCarouselSize, el);
        varCarouselSize ++;
    }
});

function itemLoadCallbackFunction(carousel, state)
{
    //alert(state);
    if (state == 'init') {
        carousel.size(0);
    }
}
```